# Dynamic Page Numbering in Livecycle Designer ES2

Tags: pagination, designer, livecycle, livecycle-designer, xfa

I have five "pages" in a PDF I have created.  Each page has an associated Master Page that dictates that "page"'s layout, header, footer, etc.  I also included a second page in the layout for each that properly re-adjusts the header/footer.  When I say "page" what I am referring to is unique subforms (insert page from the hierarchy) that are individual forms.

An Intro page contains fields that are used on all the subsequent pages as well as a list the user selects to enable (un-hide) the pages coded into the PDF.  Everything works great except for page numbering.  I need the page numbering to start as Page 1 of x for each new page that the user un-hides based on their selection.

Page Hierarchy and associated master pages:

Intro     Intro
PBL       PBLMaster (PBLM1, PBLM2)
Improve   ImproveMaster (ImprvM1, ImprvM2)
Implement ImplementMaster (ImpM1, ImpM2)
Control   ControlMaster (ConM1, ConM2)

Each page has the following set under OBJECT - PAGINATION:

PBL -

Place: On Page PBLMM1
Keep With: (neither are selected)
After: Continue filling parent
If dataset must be paginated:
Overflow: Go To Page PBLM2

And the same for each other page as appropriate.

In the Master Pages I have each Object - Pagination set as:

Include page in numbering selected
For the first master page (M1) I state Start at 1
For the next page (M2) I state to continue numbering from Previous Document in batch

However, as I unhide pages they all are paginated, starting at Page 1 with no re-setting to a new Page 1 when the new Master Page is invoked.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share your form? It would be really helpful.

Comment: @poliglot - I can, how do we attach it here?  I do not have an FTP site or server I can park it on and URL reference to.

Comment: You can use [filedropper](http://www.filedropper.com/) for example.

Comment: @poliglot OK - http://www.filedropper.com/frankenformrev1

Answer (score 3):

I have two forms in a single PDF. Both are flowing on to unlimited number of pages. I have the page numbering displaying as 1 to x for the first form and 1 to y for the second form (both are in the same physical pdf). I think this is what you are trying to do.

Here is my solution:

I have two Master Pages, eg Page1 and Page2. Each with a currentPage and pageCount field.

On the Design View, I have two body subforms at the root called ministry_document and proponent_document. The proponent_document pagination starts on the Page2 master page.

The javascript in the Master Pages paging fields is this:

**Page1.currentPage layout event:**

```
this.rawValue = xfa.layout.page(Page1);
```

**Page1.pageCount layout event:**

```
this.rawValue = xfa.layout.pageSpan(ministry_document);
```

**Page2.currentPage layout event:**

```
this.rawValue = xfa.layout.page(Page2) - xfa.layout.pageSpan(ministry_document);
```

**Page2.pageCount layout event:**

```
this.rawValue = xfa.layout.pageSpan(proponent_document);
```